# How will TCP protocol delay packets transferring when one of packets is dropped?

Tags: sockets, tcp

If client socket sends:

1. Packet A - dropped
2. Packet B
3. Packet C

Will server socket receive and queue B and C and then when A is received B and C will be passed to the server application immediately? Or B and C will be resent too? Or no packets will be sent at all until A is delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a sophisticated protocol that changes many parameters depending on the current network state, there are whole books written about the subject. The clearest way to answer your question is to say that TCP generally maintains a given send 'window' size in bytes. This is the amount of data that will be sent until previously sent acknowledgments are successfully returned.

In older TCP specifications a dropped packet within that window would result in a complete resend of data from the dropped packet onwards. To solve this problem as it's obviously a little wasteful, TCP now employs a selective acknowledgment (SACK) option ([RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018)). This would result in just the lost/corrupted packet being resent.

Back to your example, assuming the window size is large enough to encompass all three packets, and providing you are taking advantage of the latest TCP standard (don't see why you wouldn't), if packet A were dropped only packet A would be resent. If all packets are individually larger than the window then the packets must be sent and acknowledged sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the latencies. In general, first A is resent. If the client gets it and already has B and C, it can acknowledge them as well.

If this happens fast enough, B and C won't be resent, or maybe only B.